# Perform SHA-256 on input

Tags: c++, cryptography

This code is intended to take input as a string, do a SHA-256 hash on the string, and return the result.

It works correctly for the standard test vectors (test code included at the bottom). I'm particularly interested in your thoughts about whether it would be a good idea for it to accept input in forms other than a string (e.g., be able to work directly with a `std::ifstream`).

Another possibility that has occurred to me (but I'm not sure if it's worthwhile) would be to have it accept a pair of iterators. The (somewhat) unusual part about that is that even though we don't care about the form of the source, we do care about assuring that the iterator's value_type is `char` (or possibly a signed/unsigned variant).

First the header:

```
// sha256.h
#ifndef SHA_256_H_INCLUDED
#define SHA_256_H_INCLUDED

// This is a relatively straightforward implementation of SHA-256. It makes no particular
// attempt at optimization, instead aiming toward easy verification against the standard.
// To that end, many of the variable names are identical to those used in FIPS 180-2 and
// FIPS 180-3. 
//
// The code should be fairly portable, within a few limitations:
// 1. It requires that 'char' have 8 bits. In theory this is avoidable, but I don't think
// it's worth the bother.
// 2. It only deals with inputs in (8-bit) bytes. In theory, SHA-256 can deal with a number of 
// bits that's not a multiple of 8, but I've never needed it. Since the padding always results
// in a byte-sized stream, the only parts that would need changing would be reading and padding
// the input. The main hashing portion would be unaffected.
//
// Originally written in February 2008 for SHA-1.
// Converted to SHA-256 sometime later (sorry, I don't remember exactly when).
// 
// You can use this software any way you want to, with following limitations
// (shamelessly stolen from the Boost software license):
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT
// SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE
// FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
// ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
// DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
// 
// If you put this to real use, I'd be happy to hear about it. If you find a bug, 
// I'd be interested in hearing about that too. There's even a pretty good chance 
// that I'll try to fix it, though I certainly can't guarantee that.
// 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1600
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

namespace crypto { 
namespace {
    struct ternary_operator { 
        virtual uint32_t operator()(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) = 0;
    };
}

class sha256 { 
    static const size_t hash_size = 8;
    static const size_t min_pad = 64;
    static const size_t block_bits = 512;
    static const size_t block_bytes = block_bits / 8;
    static const size_t block_words = block_bytes / 4;

    std::vector<uint32_t> K;
    std::vector<uint32_t> H;
    std::vector<uint32_t> W;
    std::vector<ternary_operator *> fs;
    std::vector<uint32_t> temp;

    static const size_t block_size = 16;
    static const size_t bytes_per_word = 4;
    size_t total_size;

    // hash a 512-bit block of input.
    //
    void hash_block(std::vector<uint32_t> const &block);

    // Pad the input to a multiple of 512 bits, and add the length
    // in binary to the end.
    static std::string pad(std::string const &input);

    // Turn 64 bytes into a block of 16 uint32_t's.
    std::vector<uint32_t> make_block(std::string const &in);

public:
    // Construct a SHA-256 object. More expensive that typical 
    // ctor, but not expected to be copied a lot or anything
    // like that, so it should be fairly harmless.
    sha256();

    // The two ways to provide input for hashing: as a stream or a string.
    // Either way, you get the result as a vector<uint32_t>. It's a fairly
    // small vector, so even if your compiler doesn't do return-value 
    // optimization, the time for copying isn't like to be significant.
    // 
    std::vector<uint32_t> operator()(std::string const &input);

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, sha256 const &s);
};
}

#endif
```

And then the implementation:

```
#include "sha256.h"

namespace crypto {
namespace {
    uint32_t word(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        a &= 0xff;
        b &= 0xff;
        c &= 0xff;
        d &= 0xff;
        int val =  a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
        return val;
    }

    uint32_t ROTR(uint32_t number, unsigned bits) { 
        return (number >> bits) | (number << (32-bits));
    }

    uint32_t f1(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) { 
        return (x & y) ^ (~x & z);
    }
    uint32_t f2(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) { 
        return (x & y) ^ (x&z) ^ (y&z);
    }
    uint32_t f3(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 2) ^ ROTR(x, 13) ^ ROTR(x, 22);  
    }
    uint32_t f4(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 6) ^ ROTR(x, 11) ^ ROTR(x, 25);
    }
    uint32_t f5(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 7) ^ ROTR(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3);
    }
    uint32_t f6(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 17) ^ ROTR(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10);
    }

    uint32_t add(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

// Pad the input to a multiple of 512 bits, and add the length
// in binary to the end.
std::string sha256::pad(std::string const &input) {
    uint64_t length = input.size() * 8 + 1;
    size_t remainder = length % block_bits;
    size_t k = (remainder <= 448) ? 448 - remainder : 960 - remainder;

    std::string padding("\x80");
    padding.append(std::string(k/8, '\0'));
    --length;

    for (int i=sizeof(length)-1; i>-1; i--) {
        unsigned char byte = length >> (i*8) & 0xff;
        padding.push_back(byte);
    }

    std::string ret(input+padding);
    return ret;
}

// Turn 64 bytes into a vector of 16 uint32_t's.
std::vector<uint32_t> sha256::make_block(std::string const &in) { 
    assert(in.size() >= block_bytes);

    std::vector<uint32_t> ret(block_words);

    for (size_t i=0; i<block_words; i++) {
        size_t s = i*4;
        ret[i] = word(in[s], in[s+1], in[s+2], in[s+3]);
    }
    return ret;
}

sha256::sha256() : H(hash_size), W(64), temp(10) { 
    static const uint32_t H0[hash_size] = {
        0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 
        0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19
    };

    std::copy(H0, H0+hash_size, H.begin());
}

void sha256::hash_block(std::vector<uint32_t> const &block) {
    static const uint32_t K[] = {
        0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
        0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5, 
        0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
        0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
        0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
        0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
        0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
        0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
        0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
        0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
        0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
        0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070, 
        0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
        0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
        0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
        0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
    };

    assert(block.size() == 16);

    std::copy(block.begin(), block.end(), W.begin());
    for (int t=16; t<64; ++t) 
        W[t] = f6(W[t-2]) + W[t-7] + f5(W[t-15]) + W[t-16];
    std::copy(H.begin(), H.end(), temp.begin());

    for (int t=0; t<64; ++t) {
        temp[8] = temp[7]+f4(temp[4]) + f1(temp[4],temp[5],temp[6])+K[t]+W[t];
        temp[9] = f3(temp[0]) + f2(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
        temp[7] = temp[6];
        temp[6] = temp[5];
        temp[5] = temp[4];
        temp[4] = temp[3] + temp[8];
        temp[3] = temp[2];
        temp[2] = temp[1];
        temp[1] = temp[0];
        temp[0] = temp[8] + temp[9];
    }
    std::transform(H.begin(), H.end(), temp.begin(), H.begin(), add);
}

// Take a `std::string` as input, produce a SHA-256 hash as a vector of 16 uint32_ts'.
//
std::vector<uint32_t> sha256::operator()(std::string const &input) { 
    std::string temp(pad(input));
    std::vector<uint32_t> block(block_size);

    size_t num = temp.size()/block_bytes;

    for (unsigned block_num=0; block_num<num; block_num++) {
        size_t s;
        for (size_t i=0; i<block_size; i++) {
            s = block_num*block_bytes+i*4;
            block[i] = word(temp[s], temp[s+1], temp[s+2], temp[s+3]);
        }
        hash_block(block);  
    }
    return H;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, sha256 const &s) { 
    // Display hash result in hex.
    for (size_t i=0; i<(s.H).size(); i++)
        os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << (s.H)[i] << " ";
    return os << std::dec << std::setfill(' ') << "\n";
}
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// A minimal test harness to check that it's working correctly. Strictly black-box
// testing, with no attempt at things like coverage analysis. Nonetheless, I believe
// it should cover most of the code -- the core hashing code all gets used for every
// possible value. The padding code should be tested fairly thoroughly as well -- the
// first test is a fairly simple case, and the second the more complex one (where the 
// padding requires adding another block).
class tester {
    bool verify(uint32_t *test_val, std::vector<uint32_t> const &hash, std::ostream &os) {
        // Verify that a result matches a test value and report result.
        for (size_t i=0; i<hash.size(); i++)
            if (hash[i] != test_val[i]) {
                os << "Mismatch. Expected: " << test_val[i] << ", but found: " << hash[i] << "\n";
                return false;
            }
            os << "Message digest Verified.\n\n";
            return true;
    }

public:

    bool operator()(uint32_t *test_val, std::string const &input) {
        std::cout << "Testing hashing from string:\n\"" << input << "\"\n";
        crypto::sha256 hasher1;
        std::vector<uint32_t> hash = hasher1(input);
        std::cout << "Message digest is:\n\t" << hasher1;
        return verify(test_val, hash, std::cerr);
    }
};

int main() {

    char const *input1 = "abc";
    uint32_t result1[] = {0xba7816bf, 0x8f01cfea, 0x414140de, 0x5dae2223, 0xb00361a3, 0x96177a9c, 0xb410ff61, 0xf20015ad};

    char const *input2 = "abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq";
    uint32_t result2[] = {0x248d6a61, 0xd20638b8, 0xe5c02693, 0x0c3e6039, 0xa33ce459, 0x64ff2167, 0xf6ecedd4, 0x19db06c1};

    bool correct = tester()(result1, input1);
    correct &= tester()(result2, input2);
    if (correct)
        std::cerr << "All Tests passed!\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Test Failed!\n";
}
#endif
```

Comment: Reinventing the wheel. While it may be fun I do think I would ever use any crypto software that has not come from authoritative crypto site validated by lots of people in the field.

Comment: @Loki Lost in negation? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Virtual operator?

```
struct ternary_operator { 
        virtual uint32_t operator()(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) = 0;
    };
```

Personally I thinks this obfuscates the meaning and makes it harder to see that the call is using virtual dispatch (but that is just an opinion there is nothing technically wrong here).

I have a hard time following the logic here:

```
std::string sha256::pad(std::string const &input) {
```

Also the comment does not accurately reflect what it does:

```
// Pad the input to a multiple of 512 bits, and add the length
// in binary to the end.
```

After decoding this I find that you are adding the length to the end. **BUT** the length takes it upto the 512 bit byte boundary. It is not added after the string has been padded.

I assume this:

```
for (int i=sizeof(length)-1; i>-1; i--) {
    unsigned char byte = length >> (i*8) & 0xff;
    padding.push_back(byte);
}
```

Is trying to compensate for endianeess. I would rather see a standard function here. Something like `htonl()` or an equivalent.

I assume there is a reason that the padding starts with: '\x80`. It would be nice that is in the comment. There must be a technical reason you are not '\0' padding the string.

```
std::string padding("\x80");
padding.append(std::string(k/8, '\0'));
```

I prefer to always use {} in sub-statements. That way my code looks consistent:

```
for (int t=16; t<64; ++t) 
    W[t] = f6(W[t-2]) + W[t-7] + f5(W[t-15]) + W[t-16];
```

It always worries my bare statement inside an if. Especially with function calls that potentially look like macros.